# Nested dictionary to database tables with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlalchemy

Assuming a database with tables G, P, and C. A one-to-many relationship exists between G and P, as well between P and C.

Having now a nested dictionary:

```
db_entry = {
    "G_key_1": {
        "G_col_1": 11,
        "G_col_2": 12,
        "G_Ps": [
            {
                "P_col_1": 21,
                "P_col_2": 22,
                "P_Cs": [
                    {
                        "C_col_1": 31,
                        "C_col_2": 32,
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there a nice way to add the `db_entry` nested dictionary to the DB? At the moment I just loop over all the children since there are only 3 levels in the dictionary. But for dictionaries with more than 3 levels it would not be possible any longer.

Comment: make a recursive function to iterate over key and value pair again and again until the value is not a dictionary.

Comment: There is nothing already implemented in SQLAlchemy that allows for this to be performed easier?

Comment: You can have a look at Marshmallow. https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. Sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: As pointed out by others, make a recursive function that traverses your dictionary, converting suitable dictionaries to model objects. Handle lists as relationships, and you're pretty much done. SQLAlchemy will handle the rest (inserting in correct order etc.).